# Make all incoming emails be tracked in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

How do I make all incoming mail to specific user be synced into CRM? I have an on-premise Dynamics CRM 2011.

Is this some Email Router setting? I'm very new in Dynamics CRM administration.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you'll need to configure the email router. This is a large topic but you could get started [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699786(v=crm.5).aspx).

There is also more documentation in the Dynamics CRM implementation guide.

Comment: Also a general overview of planning an email integration [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699738(v=crm.5).aspx)